# Connecting Wifi Dongle to VMware while main computer is connect to LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vmware

I have a Work PC that is connected to the office network thru LAN. I have a Wifi USB Dongle with me and I want it connected thru my Personal Pocket Wifi but to be used by my VM. I use VMware® Workstation 7 and I have installed myself a 32bit Windows XP. Could I use my Work PC and its network seperately from my Personal Pocket Wifi and use this Wifi network solely for my VM? If somehow I wish to download large files over the internet and I do not want my office network to slowdown and at the sametime I can still work whilst downloading.

I can do this without problem using my Tethered IPHONE w/ Mobile internet but I couldnt show a separate device for my USB dongle in my VMware toolbars.

Comment: Are you trying do this with the approval of your IT department?

Comment: Ok to avoid comments like this, I am saying that that this is my small and starting software company. I do not wish my employees getting slow connections because I am downloading large software files. I can clearly do this using my laptop and seperate from my desktop PC. My curiosity wanted to do this somehow if it is possible instead of using 2 computers I can basically save time and trouble by just using 1 computer with a VM in it.